# How to Deploy Android Apps Using Xamarin Studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have created a demo apps Hello Android From Xamarin Studio It's Not Deploy when i Run.
in demo tutorial it's running fine and then it's deploy means that it's install first time and then we can use but in my created demo it is not install. please any one resolve my problem. why it is not work?

Please look below link for more details About Error:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6994/after-the-emulator-starts-up-and-slide-the-lock-button-my-apps-not-installed-means-it-s-not-display?new=1

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too, it was resolved when i update my hard disc to ssd. Try to open the emulator first, and then run the demo app.